# Issue with Directory Structure Generated by Gradle compileQuerydsl

Tags: java, spring-boot, dsl

I proceeded while watching the online lecture, and now I'm not sure if the version has changed or what, but even if I run compileQuerydsl, only the highest directory is created, not the target model.
My build.gradle and model are as follows. I would appreciate it if you could tell me the reason.

This is the build.gradl

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
compileOnly {
extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'

implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2' // import javax.persistence.Entity;
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'

//QueryDSL 추가
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0'
//    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: '5.0.0'
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0'
}
```

and this is the ExampleTable.java (model)

```
import jakarta.persistence.\*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExampleTable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String name;

private int age;

public ExampleTable(Long id, String name, int age) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}

public ExampleTable() {

}
}
```

and this is the result of me running compileQuerydsl.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIkjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

with this `build.gradle` the Query class is generated with the `com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl` plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    querydsl.extendsFrom implementation, compileOnly, runtimeOnly, annotationProcessor

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'

    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2' // import javax.persistence.Entity;
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'

//QueryDSL 추가
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
//    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: '5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
}
querydsl {
    jpa = true
    library = 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

add following line to the configurations in order to allow the annotationprocessor to find the jpa classes from classpath:

```
 querydsl.extendsFrom implementation, compileOnly, runtimeOnly, annotationProcessor
```

in the dependendcy section add the jakarta classifier:

```
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'  
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
```

and finally add to configure the annotation processor:

```
  querydsl {
    jpa = true
    library = 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
   }

   compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
   }
```

---

with this `build.gradle` you can generate the `querydsl` sources without the `com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl` plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
    implementation  "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta"

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'

    annotationProcessor ( 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta',
            "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0")

}
```

using `annotationProcessor` task and telling gradle where the annotationProcessor is and where other dependecies are located:

```
annotationProcessor ( 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta',
            "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0")
```

the generated files can be found in[image: build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main]